# Question on a proof that there are infinitely many primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

There are several ways to prove this fact, and I can think of two reasonably clear ways, but my professor presented a sketch of a proof that I can't quite follow. I'm going to replicate his logic as best as I can.

**Theorem.** There are infinitely many primes.

*Proof.* Assume for a contradiction that there are only finitely many primes, which we can list as $p_1, p_2, p_3, \ldots, p_m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, form the product 
\begin{align*}
N = \mathop{\Pi}\limits_{i=1}^m p_i + 1.
\end{align*}
From here there are several ways to proceed. But, this is where I find myself getting confused.

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under multiplication and addition, $N \in \mathbb{Z}$, and since $N > p_i, \forall i$, $N$ is not a prime. So, there exists some $p_i$ such that $p_i \mid N$, so $\exists a \in \mathbb{Z}, a \cdot p_i = N$, i.e., $a \cdot p_i = p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot p_3 \cdots p_m + 1$.

From here, my professor concluded that $\frac{1}{p_i} \in \mathbb{Z}$, an absurdity and thus a contradiction. I can't quite figure out how to get there. If we divide both sides through by $p_i$, since $1 \leq i \leq m$, we get $a$ on the LHS and two terms on the RHS, one of which is a product of $m - 1$ primes (after cancelling) and one of which is $\frac{1}{p_i}$. From here, perhaps we could subtract the product of $m - 1$ terms, clearly an integer by closure under multiplication, from $a$, also an integer. Then, by closure under subtraction, $a$ less this product is also an integer, in which case we've found our contradiction.

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I disagree with the use of "division" in any proof for elementary number theory.  The concept of division is usually only formally introduced much later in a course from where you appear to be at the moment.

So, we get to letting $N=\prod\limits_{i=1}^mp_i + 1$ and we determined that $N>p_i$ for all $i$ and so $N$ is not one of the elements in our list of primes.  Ergo, $N$ must be composite (*by theorem proved earlier, every natural number is either 0, 1, prime, or composite*).  That is, there is some naturals $j$ and $a$ such that $N=a\cdot p_j$.

That is, $a\cdot p_j = p_1\cdot p_2\cdots p_j\cdots p_m + 1$

Now, by subtracting and factoring, we have $1 = p_j\cdot(a - p_1\cdot p_2\cdots p_{j-1}\cdot p_{j+1}\cdots p_m)$

Note, however, that $(a-p_1\cdots p_m)$ is an integer and so too is $p_j$.  Notice that this would then imply that $p_j$ is a divisor of $1$, but $1$ has no divisors except itself.  This is our contradiction.

Note, the above argument completely bypassed the need for referring to divi*sion*, though it does make use of divi*sibility* (*something which is perfectly acceptable to refer to and use in these level of proofs*).

Comment: I think division is fine here, as I cannot imagine a construction of $\mathbb{Q}$ that would depend on the existence of infinitely many primes! I think division with remainder and the Euclidean algorithm are more than sufficient to construct $\mathbb{Q}$ with all the necessary bells and whistles (ring structure, reduced forms, total order, floor and ceiling, prime factorization).